# Set anonymous function's name

Tags: javascript, node.js, anonymous-function

Although a Functions 'name' property is read-only, is there some trick to set it?

Here's a simplified case where it would help:

```
class O{
    myFn;
    constructor(fn){
        this.myFn= fn;    // Here I want to set the name of fn / this.myFn 
    }
}

new O( () => {      
    console.log("hello");  // breakpoint here the function name is "(anonymous function)"
}).myFn();
```

I could name it at the definition:

```
new O(  function namedFunction () {      
    console.log("hello");  
}).myFn();
```

but I am looking for a way to name/rename it later.

(I am working on node.js I am not sure if this question would be valid for browsers)

Comment: why do you want to do it ?

Comment: @ashishsingh To have a more descriptive stack while debugging

Comment: It's true that anonymous functions don't lead to a very descriptive stack trace, and sometimes this can be a problem. But if it is for you, just give the function a name when you define it - it was your choice to make it anonymous in the first place. Or are you looking for some way to dynamically change the name of an already-declared function, for some reason? (Not sure if you can do that.)

Comment: The actual usage is for a homemade tester, here clarity and flexibility are useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging in `Function.prototype.name` docs I've found

> To change it, you could use Object.defineProperty() though.

(it's at the end of the section https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#Inferred_function_names)

So this does what I wanted:

```
class O{
    constructor(fn){

        Object.defineProperty(fn,'name',{value:"lateNamedFunction", writable:false});

        this.myFn= fn;
    }
}
```

This may provide some interesting possibilities...